# "Бал" или "балом"?

Tags: лексика

В песне поётся:

> сатана там правит бал...

Почему **бал**, а не **балом**?

Comment: ХэшКод такой строгий!

Answer (score 7):

Это не песня, а ария Мефистофеля из оперы Гуно "Фауст".

У глагола "править" есть книжное значение "совершать, осуществлять, исполнять". В этом случае последующее существительное — в винительном падеже: править суд, молебен, бал.

Comment: Не сказал бы что значение чмсто книжное... Это, имхо, то же значение, что и в "править текст, рукопись", "править инструмент" - делать правильным.

Comment: Нет. Править  рукопись  или  текст  это  значит - исправлять  ошибки.  А  если  к  инструменту,  то  это  конечный  этап  заточки  лезвия.