# Почему говорят "править бал"?

Tags: фразеология

Почему "Править бал", а не "Править балом"? Может, второй вариант тоже уместен?

Answer (score 4):

Мне кажется, что выражение "править бал" употребляется чаще в переносном значении: заправлять чем-то, главенствовать над чем-то, диктовать свои правила. А "править балом", "управлять балом" относится уже конкретно к балу и больше ничему.

Answer (score 3):

Верно: **править бал** (т. е. проводить, совершать бал, а не управлять им). См. [как употребляется выражение "править бал(ом)](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search_answer/?s=%EF%F0%E0%E2%E8%F2%FC+%E1%E0%EB).

Answer (score 3):

Повтор.

Полный и вполне грамотный ответ [тут](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/1394/%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC).

ЗЫ Меня более удивляет сама идея "править балом". Может, кто-то пояснит, откуда она берётся, по какому шаблону? Никому ж не приходит в голову, например, "справлять юбилеем" или "править рукописью"? "Править чем" - это совсем другое значение... Неужели носители языка этого в массе не чувствуют?!

Comment: Может, из-за ассоциации с "править страной, государством, народом". Ведь у слова "править" первое и, по сути, основное значение "руководить, управлять (кем? чем?)". А значение "совершать, осуществлять, исполнять" далеко не настолько популярное. ("Править" - "исправлять" пока не в счет.)